# Using paired t-test for data with multiple outcomes on a practice example

Tags: r, t-test, paired-data

This is something that I'm trying on my own. I needed some expert opinion on whether or not what I'm doing is okay. I'm using R v3.4.3.

So, what I'm thinking is, having three outcomes (continuous) and 1 another variable called `effect` (perhaps poorly chosen name) that has two types of observations (`A` or `B`). Each outcomes has pre and post.

First I tried to check if there's a difference in each Outcomes. I used paired t-test. I assumed normality.

Then, I stratified the data using `effect` variable. I divided the dataset into two subsets. Then I ran another paired t-test for each effects. Then, I measured if there's a difference is significant for each outcomes for each effects.

The question is, is it okay to do it this way? Is there anything I'm violating or not accounting for?

If the method I used is okay, and the assumptions for normality is not met, can I use `wilcoxon.test` or do I have to do something before I can use it?

**Code:**

```
id <- seq(1:156)
effect <- c(rep("A", 20),rep("B", 136))

# First outcome
outcome1.pre <- rnorm(156, mean = 0.71, sd = 0.10)
outcome1.post <- rnorm(156, mean = 0.75, sd = 0.12)

# Second outcome
outcome2.pre <- rnorm(156, mean = 24.43, sd = 18.13)
outcome2.post <- rnorm(156, mean = 27.70, sd = 20.16)


# Third outcome
outcome3.pre <- rnorm(156, mean = 4.6, sd = 1.9)
outcome3.post <- rnorm(156, mean = 7.1, sd = 3.3)


df <- data.frame(id, effect, outcome1.pre, outcome1.post, outcome2.pre, outcome2.post, outcome3.pre, outcome3.post)

# outcome 1 paired test
t.test(outcome1.post, outcome1.pre, paired = T)

# outcome 1 paired test
t.test(outcome2.post, outcome2.pre, paired = T)

# outcome 1 paired test
t.test(outcome3.post, outcome3.pre, paired = T)


# outcome by effect

effect.A <- df[df$effect == "A",]
effect.B <- df[df$effect == "B", ]

# effect A - Outcomes
t.test(effect.A$outcome1.pre, effect.A$outcome1.post, paired = T)

t.test(effect.A$outcome2.pre, effect.A$outcome2.post, paired = T)

t.test(effect.A$outcome3.pre, effect.A$outcome3.post, paired = T)


# effect B - Outcomes
t.test(effect.B$outcome1.pre, effect.B$outcome1.post, paired = T)

t.test(effect.B$outcome2.pre, effect.B$outcome2.post, paired = T)

t.test(effect.B$outcome3.pre, effect.B$outcome3.post, paired = T)
```

I could really use somebody's help on this one to make sure I'm understanding things correctly before I move to another level.

Is there anything else I can do in terms of analysis that I can learn and help make this analysis better?

Comment: What is the goal of this experiment? If you only want to test whether there is a difference for a subset of population then this everything is perfectly fine. You only need to ensure that a subset is properly sampled, which in your case it is.

Comment: The goal is to show whether difference is significant or not for each effects and overall. Could you please elaborate “properly sampled”. If I had gone out and collected data, then check for normality. Is that what you mean? Could you add your response as answer so that I can mark it?